# Register without username and password or not to register?

Tags: joomla3.0

I want to develop a Joomla webapp for users who may not have a working Email Id. They will visit the website hardly once/twice a year. So they may not even remember their Username and password. Most of them will access website through mobile phone.

So, my plan is -

1. Users will provide core personal details like First Name, Last Name, Date of Birth and Mobile No.
2. Verify Mobile No. by sending and receiving one time password.
3. Search whether record already exists.
4. If record (an application form) exists, show record to edit / print.
5. If record does not exist, create new application form.

My question is -

1. Is it possible to achieve this without User Registration and Login to the site?
2. Is it possible to create users by formulating hidden unique Username and Password ( with a fixed single Email Id)? And is it also possible to login with these formulated and hidden Username and password?
3. What will be the Pros and Cons of creating and not creating Registered Users?
4. As a beginner I may not be able to create my own component. What extensions/plugins can i use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are accepting and verifying mobile number then consider this as registration process. It is not necessary to take User name and password for registration.

Comment: True, but then they will not be Joomla's Registered users. Do I miss any benefits of having them Joomla registered users?